# Change web browser page with Arduino or similar solution

Tags: php, mysql, browser, arduino, rfid

I'm developing a project, which registers RFID card entries and such, managed by an SQL Database.

I'm using an Arduino to read the cards, send the RFID data and reader ID through a PHP program, which then processes the data, and registers it on MySQL.

Registering the cards on the database is my problem.
How do I make it so, Arduino changes or opens a WebBrowser page, or that when I have a certain link open, like something.com/RegisterCard.php, when I read a card, it inputs it automatically into the registering field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing something similar, instead of reading an RFID, i read several sensors to store data, and then the arduino itself ask for some variable (stored on the daatabase) and respond to the value of it.

What Ive found the easiest way, may not the most efficent, but works.

My method involves a PHP "interpreter" that depending on what the arduino sent, will store into the database, or read and return.

So more like **" when I have a certain link open, like something.com/RegisterCard.php, when I read a card, it inputs it automatically into the registering field."**

For example, to store Latitude/Longitude variables from my gps through GSM shield i use this code:

```
  sim908.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"YOU_WEB_SERVER_URL_/insert.php?latitude=");
  sim908.print(latitude);
  sim908.print("&longitude=");
  sim908.print(longitude);
  sim908.println("\"");
  delay(2000);
  sim908.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0"); //now GET action
  delay(2000);
```

I have a page "insert.php" that handles the data, and stores it into the database.

Here is my php handler

```
<html> 

<body> 

<?php 
//funcion para adquirir parametros
       function getParameter($par, $default = null){
            if (isset($_GET[$par]) && strlen($_GET[$par])) return $_GET[$par];
            elseif (isset($_POST[$par]) && strlen($_POST[$par])) 
                return $_POST[$par];
            else return $default;
        }

         $latitud = getParameter("latitud");
         $longitud=getParameter("longitud");
         $evento=getParameter("evento");

         $time = time();
         $fecha = date("d-m-Y", $time);
         $hora = date("H:i:s", $time);


//Conectarse y seleccionar base de datos 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user','mysql_pass'); 
if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

echo 'ok';


$db_selected = mysql_select_db('mydatabase', $link); 


if (!$db_selected) { 
die ('Cant use ods_db : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
// Tomar los campos provenientes del Formulario 
//$latitud = $_POST['latitud']; 
//$longitud = $_POST['longitud']; 

// Insertar campos en la Base de Datos 
$que = "INSERT INTO tracklog (fecha, hora,latitud, longitud,event) "; 
$que.= "VALUES ('".$fecha."','".$hora."','".$latitud."', '".$longitud."', '".$evento."') "; 
$res = mysql_query($que, $link) or die(mysql_error()); 
$orden = mysql_insert_id();
// Cerrar conexión a la Base de Datos 
mysql_close($link); 
?> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was a solution that I've thought about previously, but it would require the user to choose from a list of "AwaitingRegistry" entries, which would be, a bump in an otherwise smooth piece of paper (#BestMetafors2016). I want to know if it's possible to have, lets say Register.php opened in browser, and as soon as I read a card it inputs the value it read on the form.